# I can't show validation error message when direct page

Tags: php, codeigniter, login-script

I have this function for login checker, when `$email` and `$password` wrong I want add redirect to another page, like login on a facebook page, when `$email` and `$password` incorect they direct to different page but still login page(but not the same page) and sent the message it was incorect `$email` or `$password` to the page

```
function basisdata_cek($password){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $result = $this->login->login($email,$password);
    if($result){
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row){
            $sess_array = $arrayName = array('kode_daftar'=>$row->kode_daftar, 'email'=>$row->email, 'password'=>$row->password);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('basisdata_cek','invalid email or password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I add redirect page like this

```
}else{
    redirect(base_url('index.php/login'),'refresh');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('basisdata_cek','invalid email or password');
    return false;
}
```

It's still direct page when it's incorrect email & password but the message of `form_validation` won't show up.

Comment: The information is lost on the redirect because the whole process starts over. The next page call knows nothing about the last page unless you use sessions to pass info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not possible to get form_validation message if you redirect. But you can use flashdata for this.

Add this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` in `application/config/autoload.php` and   Put this code in your login page

```
if ($this->session->flashdata('basisdata_cek')) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">';
    echo '<p>' . $this->session->flashdata('basisdata_cek') . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
```

And put flash `$this->session->set_flashdata` instead `$this->form_validation->set_message` before `redirect` :

```
 }else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('basisdata_cek', 'Invalid email or password');
    redirect(base_url('index.php/login'),'refresh');        
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: please check i change the answer